# firestore internal assertion failed

Tags: android, firebase, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working in a Ionic3 app with Firestore and AngularFirestore2.
Everything is working fine in browser, login, document, collection, insert new etc.
Trying to deploy the app in Ionic View, Firestore does not work properly, the error message is

```
FIRESTORE INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED AsyncQueue is already failed The parameter is not a valid key
```

I also tried to build the apk with cordova build, but the problem is the same.
It's not a problem with Firestore permission rules, because read and write are allowed for all documents.
Does anyone get the same issue?
Thanks

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-firestore-discuss/hjng5VgktPM

Answer (score 3):

In my case, this error was because I enable AngularFire persistence offline.

I just remove this line of my *app.module.ts* and it work fine again.

```js
    // AngularFirestoreModule.enablePersistence(),
```